# Trying to set up a fleet of computers for wifi

Tags: windows, windows-7, wifi

I have an interesting situation.  I have a fleet of trucks that will each have a Verizon Mifi installed in it.  Each Mifi will have an SSID such as "SysServ1", SysServ2", etc.  We have a total of about 25 trucks that will have these Mifi's installed.

Now, I have about 120 computers that I need to map to ANY of those Mifi's at any given moment.  I don't care if the Mifi's all have the same password, but I can't give the crew's the password because the Admin doesn't want them attaching their phones or whatever to the Mifi and sucking up company data usage.

So the question is this, how can I configure 120 computers to attach to any of a list of 25 SSIDs that might currently be available.  My thought was maybe there was a way to write a config for windows wifi that could have the password and SSID's stored somewhere on the computer so that when the computer is within range of an available SSID it could just automatically connect to it.  But I don't know how to achieve this.

BTW, the end user doesn't have access to the C drive outside their user folder, so I can put the file in system or system32 and they won't be able to get the password from it.

Any ideas or tips?

Comment: I recommend looking into Salt: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits you requirement, because you don't provide the bottom line. :)

I think you can simplify things to configure all MIFIs to same SSID and same password.

So you only need to configure 25 MIFIs and 120 computers, each once.

You also can think of importing/exporting wifi settings by this [reference](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4081/easily-backup-import-your-wireless-network-settings-in-windows-7/).

Comment: What happens when two trucks come within range of each other?

Comment: The trucks may collide and cause significant damage to each other. As for the computers, they would connect to the first available MiFi, which shouldn't be a problem if the data plan is shared across them.

Comment: Yes, as @Zim mentions, computer itself usually can roam between them automatically, just like normal company wireless infrastructure -  you connect to company SSID, don't need to manual switch when you go from frist floor to Nth floor.

Answer (score 0):

See the question [Create Wi Fi network by C++ or C# and Windows API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865543/create-wi-fi-network-by-c-or-c-sharp-and-windows-api) for some ideas on how to do this programattically.

Something like the [Managed WiFi Library](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) might help too.

Otherwise, exporting/importing as @alfred said above seems to be the non-coding way to go about it.

Note, you might get better answers on IT-admin questions on [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) (another StackExchange site).